# Docker to reuse build time dedicated RUN cache in docker run

Tags: docker, caching, build

For the Docker's [dedicated RUN cache](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#use-the-dedicated-run-cache),

> Using the explicit cache with the --mount flag keeps the contents of the target directory preserved between builds. When this layer needs to be rebuilt, then it'll use the apt cache in /var/cache/apt.

I tried to use the `--mount` flag during docker build, but found that such cache are not available when I tried to `docker run` the built image. I don't know if it my own fault of not having such build time cache during run time, but anyway,

Is there any mechanizm for me to utilize such build time cache during run time?